# error al mostrar valor de un JSON en JS, HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, array, json

Al obtener JSON, muestra :

```
  console.log(rpta); 

[[{ "VdiasTranscurridos": "5" }]]
```

Intento leerlo como:

```
$("#diasTranscurridos").html(rpta.VdiasTranscurridos);

$("#diasTranscurridos").html(rpta[0].VdiasTranscurridos);
```

Y no muestra nada o muestra error.

Comment: Saludos. El detalle es que recibes un `array` dentro de un `array` y es dentro de éste último `array` que tiene el JSON; para tu caso y escenario que muestras debe ser `$("#diasTranscurridos").html(rpta[0][0].VdiasTranscurridos);`.

Comment: Amigo,  ahora tengo esta respuesta en la consola : "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: can't access property 0, rpta[0] is undefined", como si al response no estaria definida, pero ahora veo que en el console.log(), sale : <empty string> y el mensaje del JSON, sale en Network, response , envio la funcion donde lo obtengo : function ver_dias_transcurridos(V_expediente) {
        fetchGetJSON("Reportes/diasTranscurridos/?IdExpediente=" + V_expediente, function (rpta) {
            console.log(rpta);
            $("#diasTranscurridos").html(rpta[0][0].VdiasTranscurridos);

        });

    }

Comment: Saludos. Debes revisar y verificar la información así como los escenarios que puedes obtener (es decir, el JSON con datos o vacío -de lo básico-); lo que mencionas es más tratamiento de errores y escenarios.

Comment: Gracias, amigo... el problema era la configuración... era una aplicación legada... y no todos trabajan con estándares...., más que depuración, había que hacer un trabajo de fontanería...